# Can appcache be partially updated?

Tags: web-applications, html5-appcache

I'm using appcache to make PWA, and in a few trys I've done appcache does not seem to be updated partially, say All or None.

but I can't be sure if it's guaranteed or not.

Google does not show any reference so I came here.

Thanks for reading and I'll appreciate your answer!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache

Comment: Once all the files have been successfully retrieved, they are moved into the real offline cache automatically, and a cached event is sent to the applicationCache object. Since the document has already been loaded into the browser from the cache, the updated document will not be rendered until the document is reloaded (either manually or programatically).